# Comprobar dias del 1 al 5 de cada mes

Tags: php, base-de-datos, date, datetime

Les comento, necesito que el sistema los dias del `1` al `5` de cada mes verifique si personas de un condominio realizaron el pago, sino para colocarlos en mora. Estuve investigando y crreo que date period con date interval, es lo mas cercano a esa funcion, por el momento tengo lo siguiente, sin embargo no realiza lo solicitado, espero puedan ayudarme.

El valor fecha de la tabla `pago_p` esta en formato `date`

```html
<?php
require_once('../conexion.php');
$hoy = getdate();
$begin = new DateTime( '2018-08-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2018-08-31' );


$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pago_p"; 
    $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    
    while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    if(["pago"]==NULL {

    echo '<script> alert("No realizaste el pago en la fecha determinada"); </script>';

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ya intento con `strtotime()` ???

Comment: Acabo de investigarla, pero como la coloco para que me funcione en el problema planteado? :( gracias

Comment: Dame un minuto planteo el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sería algo así ?

```
$año_actual = date("Y");
$mes_actual = date("m");
//Fecha adaptada para MySQL.
$inicio = $año_actual."-".$mes_actual."-"."01"." 00:00:00";
$fin = $año_actual."-".$mes_actual."-"."05"." 00:00:00";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM pago_p WHERE campo_fecha BETWEEN '".$inicio."' AND '".$fin."'"; 
$res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
//Resultado contiene todos los que pagaron en tiempo y forma, para encontrar lo inverso se puede negar la consulta.
$resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
```

En realidad creo que esta mal planteada la pregunta quizá, porque sí el sistema debe verificar automáticamente "algo" ciertos días, se debería hacer con un cronjob.

Answer (score 1):

leyendo tu codigo, y en uso de tu sintaxis, cree un algoritmo que te hara lo que necesitas, validar los 5 dias de cada mes si se realizo el pago.

entonces quedaria asi:

```
<?php
    require_once('../conexion.php');
    // $hoy = getdate();
    //fecha inicial
    $begin = new DateTime( '2018-08-01' );
    //fecha final que comprede que debe evaluar los primeros 5 dias 
    $end = new DateTime( '2018-08-05' );
    //agregamos un dia mas para que cuente el 5 en la otra fecha ponemos hasta el 6
    $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 

    //Creamos el intervalo de tiempo para que sea por cada dia 
    $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

    $alerta="";
    //recorremos la varaible que ahora almacena el rango entre 1 - 5
    foreach($daterange as $date){
        //creamos el formato de la fecha
        $fecha_dia= $date->format("Ymd");
        //hacemos la consulta con la condicion de la fecha para validar los correspondientes dias que se necesitan
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM pago_p WHERE fechas_campo =' $fecha_dia'"; 
        $res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

        while($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
            //verificamos que en cada fila el campo "pago" no este vacio
            if(!empty($resultado["pago"])) {
                //si no esta vacio entonces realizo el pago
                //y damos valor a una variable
                $alerta="si";
            }
        }

        if ($alerta=="si") {
            //despues del ciclo imprimimos la alerta para que en cada ciclo no la repita
            echo '<script> alert("No realizaste el pago en la fecha determinada"); </script>';
        }
?>
```

Espero te sirva y la marque xD... **ReNiceCode...**

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo

Comment: De nada mi Bro, siempre es un placer para mi ayudar... ReNiceCode...

Comment: Amigo srJJ tienes alguna forma de contacto? para una duda acerca de este problema? y disculpa

Comment: jjrrdecali90@gmail.com

Comment: vale enviado, gracias